# Finding the angle of a sector

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have a circle, with an object lying at the edge. In the diagram the object is represented by the blue circle. I need to form a sector in the same way that is drawn in the diagram, given the following:

- The distance between the centre of the circle and the object, i.e. the radius r.
- The width of the object.
- The ratio between the width of the object and the length of the sector arc. e.g. 50%, meaning that half the arc length would be covered by the object.

I basically need to calculate the angle alpha that would satisfy the given ratio.

Comment: Do you know object's width ?

Comment: If the object has radius $\rho$, then the angle required is $4(2 \arcsin \frac{\rho}{2r})$.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I have the width of the object. I've fixed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w$ be the width of the object, $r$ the radius of the circle, $\rho$ the ratio of the width to the arc length and $\alpha$ the total angle of the arc.

The arc length is $\alpha r$, and $\rho = \frac{w}{\alpha r}$. Hence $\alpha = \frac{w}{\rho r}$ (radians).

Answer (score 0):

1. Compute tangents intersections between the object and the circle. How you do this depends a lot on how your objects are represented.
2. Compute the angle corresponding to this pair of points. An `aran2` kind of function might help in this step.
3. Divide that angle by the ratio you're given, i.e. by 0.5 for 50%.